# Downloaded file from Android App not visible in Downloads directory

Tags: android, download

I am in process of developing an app wherein I am downloading pdf files from a remote server. I am so far successful in downloading the PDF files on my phone via the app. The problem that I am facing is that the downloaded file is not visible in the Downloads directory on my Galaxy Nexus. When I use the file manager app I can see the file there and it opens up real nice.

I tried using the following options in my code but none of them seems to solve my problem (both these options successfully download the file and its visible in the file manager) :

```
outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
```

And

```
outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);
```

Can someone please help me with some clues ? Any hint or clue will be of great help.

Comment: Try using the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html), not sure if you can get the downloaded file otherwise into the downloads list

Comment: have a look at this method addCompletedDownload here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: when you say downloads directory, do you mean downloads app? you are saying you can see through file manager

Comment: @zapl: Thank you so much. DownloadManager works like a charm. It works like I needed. I am happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it using the DownloadManager in the following way :

```
dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Request request = new Request(
            Uri.parse("http://"));
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

     BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Complete!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```